# Installing fiona: Must the gdal version be compatible with fiona?

Tags: python, fiona

I am on Windows and using Python via Anaconda.

Python 3.8.8, 64 bit AMD64

1. I downloaded the gdal & fiona wheels from
   [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal)
   [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#fiona](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#fiona)

GDAL-3.2.3-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
Fiona-1.8.20-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl

2. Installed gdal successfully:
   Version 3.2.3
3. Add Environment Variable with the name GDAL_DATA and value =

C:\Users\yourUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\data\gdal

4. Installed Visual C++ build tools from
   https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
5. Re-start my computer
6. pip install C:/Users/Asus/anaconda3/Lib/Fiona-1.8.20-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl

But there is always error in building gdal wheel at step 6.

```
Using cached gdal 3.3.1.tar.gz .....

Failed in building wheels for gdal ...
```

Why is there a need for fiona to build wheels for gdal when I have already installed gdal?
I have added the path for the installed gdal to environment variable.

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to read a .shp file using gpd.read_file,

```
shapefile = gpd.read_file(r'C:\Users\abhir....\shapefiles\louisville.shp')
```

which threw an ImportError

```
ImportError: the 'read_file' function requires the 'fiona' package, but it is not installed or does not import correctly.
Importing fiona resulted in: DLL load failed while importing ogrext: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Apparantly, I was using different versions of GDAL and fiona combinations.

**GDAL-3.3.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl**

**Fiona-1.8.20-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl**

I had to uninstall the above versions and install the below versions. It resolved the issue.

**GDAL-3.2.3-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl**

**Fiona‑1.8.19‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl**

Comment: GDal 3.2.3 does not even exist. See the [releases](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/releases?page=1). However, Fiona 1.8.19 and GDal 3.2.2 appear to be compatible.

Answer (score 1):

I have to use

Fiona‑1.8.19‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.