# GDAL and Fiona conflicting versions but downgrading Fiona leads to a legacy-install-failure error

Tags: python-3.x, pip, conda, gdal, osgeo

This question is similar to the questions
[Installing fiona: Must the gdal version be compatible with fiona?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68973532/installing-fiona-must-the-gdal-version-be-compatible-with-fiona) and
[ImportError: the 'read_file' function requires the 'fiona' package, but it is not installed or does not import correctly. Importing fiona resulted in:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69521550/importerror-the-read-file-function-requires-the-fiona-package-but-it-is-no)
but the solutions provided are not working for me.

The original error occurs when trying to read a file using geopandas `gdf = gpd.read_file(anyshape.shp")` and this error message appears:

```
ImportError: the 'read_file' function requires the 'fiona' package, but it is not installed or does not import correctly.
Importing fiona resulted in: No module named 'Fiona'
```

This happens in a clean conda virtual environment with
Python: 3.10.4,
Fiona: 1.8.21, and
GDAL: 3.4.2, running OSX 12.3. 
Previous threads recommended downgrading Fiona to 1.8.19 and GDAL to 3.2.3 but the commands `pip install fiona==1.8.19` or `pip install fiona==1.8.20` lead to the following error:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: fiona
  Building wheel for fiona (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [78 lines of output]
      /opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py:275: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'metadata_version'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      /opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py:275: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'requires_python'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      /opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py:275: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'requires_external'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona
      copying ./fiona/_loading.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona
      copying ./fiona/env.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona
      copying ./fiona/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona
      copying ./fiona/io.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona
      copying ./fiona/drvsupport.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona
      copying ./fiona/session.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona
      copying ./fiona/inspector.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona
      copying ./fiona/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona
      copying ./fiona/logutils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona
      copying ./fiona/crs.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona
      copying ./fiona/rfc3339.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona
      copying ./fiona/vfs.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona
      copying ./fiona/transform.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona
      copying ./fiona/collection.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona
      copying ./fiona/_show_versions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona
      copying ./fiona/errors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona
      copying ./fiona/path.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona/fio
      copying ./fiona/fio/options.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona/fio
      copying ./fiona/fio/collect.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona/fio
      copying ./fiona/fio/distrib.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona/fio
      copying ./fiona/fio/env.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona/fio
      copying ./fiona/fio/insp.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona/fio
      copying ./fiona/fio/cat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona/fio
      copying ./fiona/fio/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona/fio
      copying ./fiona/fio/ls.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona/fio
      copying ./fiona/fio/rm.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona/fio
      copying ./fiona/fio/dump.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona/fio
      copying ./fiona/fio/calc.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona/fio
      copying ./fiona/fio/filter.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona/fio
      copying ./fiona/fio/load.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona/fio
      copying ./fiona/fio/main.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona/fio
      copying ./fiona/fio/info.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona/fio
      copying ./fiona/fio/helpers.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona/fio
      copying ./fiona/fio/bounds.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona/fio
      running build_ext
      building 'fiona.schema' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/include -I/opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/include -I/opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/include/python3.10 -c fiona/schema.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona/schema.o
      clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -Wl,-rpath,/opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/lib -L/opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/lib -L/opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/lib build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona/schema.o -L/opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/lib -lgdal -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona/schema.cpython-310-darwin.so
      building 'fiona._transform' extension
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/include -I/opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/include -I/opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/include/python3.10 -c fiona/_transform.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona/_transform.o -std=c++11
      clang++ -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -Wl,-rpath,/opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/lib -L/opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/lib -L/opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/lib build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona/_transform.o -L/opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/lib -lgdal -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona/_transform.cpython-310-darwin.so
      building 'fiona._geometry' extension
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/include -I/opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/include -I/opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/include/python3.10 -c fiona/_geometry.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona/_geometry.o
      fiona/_geometry.c:13026:19: error: implicit declaration of function '_PyGen_Send' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                  ret = _PyGen_Send((PyGenObject*)yf, value == Py_None ? NULL : value);
                        ^
      fiona/_geometry.c:13026:17: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'PyObject *' (aka 'struct _object *') from 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
                  ret = _PyGen_Send((PyGenObject*)yf, value == Py_None ? NULL : value);
                      ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      fiona/_geometry.c:13031:19: error: implicit declaration of function '_PyGen_Send' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                  ret = _PyGen_Send((PyGenObject*)yf, value == Py_None ? NULL : value);
                        ^
      fiona/_geometry.c:13031:17: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'PyObject *' (aka 'struct _object *') from 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
                  ret = _PyGen_Send((PyGenObject*)yf, value == Py_None ? NULL : value);
                      ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      fiona/_geometry.c:13115:19: error: implicit declaration of function '_PyGen_Send' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                  ret = _PyGen_Send((PyGenObject*)yf, NULL);
                        ^
      fiona/_geometry.c:13115:17: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'PyObject *' (aka 'struct _object *') from 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
                  ret = _PyGen_Send((PyGenObject*)yf, NULL);
                      ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      3 warnings and 3 errors generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for fiona
  Running setup.py clean for fiona
Failed to build fiona
Installing collected packages: click, fiona
  Attempting uninstall: click
    Found existing installation: click 8.1.2
    Uninstalling click-8.1.2:
      Successfully uninstalled click-8.1.2
  Attempting uninstall: fiona
    Found existing installation: Fiona 1.8.21
    Uninstalling Fiona-1.8.21:
      Successfully uninstalled Fiona-1.8.21
  Running setup.py install for fiona ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for fiona did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [36 lines of output]
      /opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py:275: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'metadata_version'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      /opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py:275: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'requires_python'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      /opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py:275: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'requires_external'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      running install
      /opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      running build_ext
      building 'fiona._geometry' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/include -I/opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/include -I/opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/include/python3.10 -c fiona/_geometry.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.10/fiona/_geometry.o
      fiona/_geometry.c:13026:19: error: implicit declaration of function '_PyGen_Send' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                  ret = _PyGen_Send((PyGenObject*)yf, value == Py_None ? NULL : value);
                        ^
      fiona/_geometry.c:13026:17: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'PyObject *' (aka 'struct _object *') from 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
                  ret = _PyGen_Send((PyGenObject*)yf, value == Py_None ? NULL : value);
                      ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      fiona/_geometry.c:13031:19: error: implicit declaration of function '_PyGen_Send' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                  ret = _PyGen_Send((PyGenObject*)yf, value == Py_None ? NULL : value);
                        ^
      fiona/_geometry.c:13031:17: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'PyObject *' (aka 'struct _object *') from 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
                  ret = _PyGen_Send((PyGenObject*)yf, value == Py_None ? NULL : value);
                      ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      fiona/_geometry.c:13115:19: error: implicit declaration of function '_PyGen_Send' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                  ret = _PyGen_Send((PyGenObject*)yf, NULL);
                        ^
      fiona/_geometry.c:13115:17: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'PyObject *' (aka 'struct _object *') from 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
                  ret = _PyGen_Send((PyGenObject*)yf, NULL);
                      ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      3 warnings and 3 errors generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  WARNING: No metadata found in /opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages
  Rolling back uninstall of fiona
  Moving to /opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/bin/fio
   from /private/var/folders/pw/g3l12fr515df7s6dpdch4qx00000gn/T/pip-uninstall-mmo446m1/fio
  Moving to /opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Fiona-1.8.21.dist-info/
   from /opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/~iona-1.8.21.dist-info
  Moving to /opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fiona/
   from /opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/~iona
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> fiona

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

╰─> Fiona
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: If you use conda, I would strongly recommend installing all packages that are available in conda and conda-forge channels directly with conda. That should reduce these incompatibility errors and issues arising from packages that require compiling. `conda install -c conda-forge geopandas` in a clean environment should work just fine.